# Is it possible to mine on your CPU and GPU at the same time?

Tags: mining, cpu-mining, gpu-mining, mining-software

I was wondering if it was possible to mine on both the CPU and the GPU at the same time on the same computer?

I have an Intel i9 7900X and an Nvidia 1080Ti, so I was hoping to get reasonable performance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Take a look at:

[xmr-stak](https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak)
[xmrig](https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig)